# Extjs How can i catch the mouse event in grid panel header column

Tags: extjs, header, grid, mouseevent, multiple-columns

Is it possible that to catch the mouse event in panel header column?
I implemented "headerclick: function(header, column, e, t,eOpts){......}" to trigger an action, but i just want to catch the event of mouse down and mouse up on the header click. Is there any solution?

Regards
Terry

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a listener for the headerclick event in the column you want:

```
columns: [{
    text: "Header Title",
    listeners: {
        headerclick: function(header, column, e, t,eOpts) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Event', 'Header clicked!');
        }
    }
}]
```

Or, if you want to listen the mouseup and mousedown, you can add listeners for the header element:

```
 columns: [{
     text: "Header Title",
     listeners: {
         mousedown: {
             element: 'el',
             fn: function() {
                 Ext.Msg.alert('Event', 'Down!');
             }
         },
         mouseup: {
             element: 'el',
             fn: function() {
                 Ext.Msg.alert('Event', 'Up!');
             }
         }
     }
 }]
```

Forking a fiddle I've found, click on "Name" header: http://jsfiddle.net/015c9k7w/

Comment: How could I do that but in a cell, not in the header?